# React Router / Warning: Location "/" did not match any routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router

**Solved**

*-->This issue was solved by adjusting indentation.*

---

I'm trying to use React Router but it's giving me errors below:

> Warning: Failed propType: Invalid prop `children` supplied to `Router`
>
> Warning: Location "/" did not match any routes

The URL I'm accessing is http://localhost:8080/. I have read other similar questions but no luck. Your help would be really appreciated!

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route} from 'react-router';

class App extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <div className="app">
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render((
  <Router>
    <Route path="/" component={App}/>
  </Router>
  ), document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Don't put `/` in your nesting routes. (see the [routeconfiguration docs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/RouteConfiguration.md#adding-an-index), too)

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I deleted / in my nesting routes but error message still remains.

Comment: One bit of advice is that it's worth reducing this to just `class App extends Component { render() { return <div>test</div>; }}` paired with `ReactDOM.render(<Router><Route path="/" component={App}/></Router>, document.getElementById('root'));`. Or, since there's not too much code in your question, just run through the react-router tutorial, making sure to copy the code properly

Comment: Hi Mike, thank you for your comment. I simplified (updated code) as you mentioned for testing purpose but still getting same error. hmm...

Comment: before we try to solve the wrong problem: which version of React-Router are you using? Because this syntax is for v2.0, so if you're using 1.x or 0.x, that error makes a lot of sense.

Comment: I'm using react-router@1.0.3...

Comment: That version was replaced by v2 on February 10th, so you can't use this syntax and have it work with an older version of react-router. If you're starting afresh, update your react-router version to `^2.0.0` first.

Comment: Hi Mike, thank you for your feedback. I finally solved this problem by just adjusting indentation =) Thank you for giving me advises though. It was very helpful to move forward. Appreciated!